# Converting tables to CSS layers

Tags: css, html, markup

I am not very good with CSS, HTML and mark-up, but after having read many and many CSS articles, I just have no idea how to get the div-elements on the right place.

- Current site in tables: http://daweb.nl/
- Current attempt in div: http://daweb.nl/daweb/

I would like to have the right-menu and content in the right place. If you have general comments regarding the current state of my HTML and CSS, please feel free. I have worked with CSS, HTML much, but never built a site from scratch with div-elements.

Comment: +1 for using Boilerplate, that's really a good start of yours!

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering! I have been able to finish it within a short while. Your responses are all very much apreciated and all good enough to be voted up!

Comment: @chronoz: look to my demo is fully featured! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple 3 div layout. You need to create 3 divs. One for the left, middle, and right-hand content. These three divs will be placed in a wrapper div.

So take your left_menu, content, and right_menu divs, give them a width and set them to float: left; so they will all be placed beside each other. Place them inside a wrapper div that is larger than all three. You're done!

Comment: Hehe, you don't know how much this float: left tip helped. I am still fairly new to CSS so I figured maybe some float central thing, but float left perfectly made it float left, but still right of the left menu_wrapper! Thanks!!

Comment: Np. Yep, float: left will shift the element to the leftmost that it can go inside it's container. Since there's another element there (another column) it will line up beside it, instead of overlapping it.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/qJBpk/10/

Check the preview [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qJBpk/10/show/).

This is a basic setup, you have a wrapper div which contain all your structure: a header, three columns and a footer.

Wrapper div has margin set to auto, this will allow it to be horizontally center placed (along with all its content) in the browser window.

The three columns have the float property set to left, so that each one is placed next to the other.

The footer has a clear property set to both, this will allow it to be placed after the most tall floated column, to avoid a layout crash.

Div elements are block level elements. This means, among other things, they take up all the avaiable width space, so no need to set a width for the #header and #footer divs.

**EDIT**

To avoid cross browser incompatibilities and issues, it's better to have a CSS reset (a set of CSS rules which will make all elements shows as much as possible the same across all browsers), like the [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/). Place it first before any other CSS code.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a good place to start learning about css positioning.
Also, after looking at your code, you may want to wrap certain elements in a wrapper div so you can position everything inside it with one CSS rule.

Instead of:

```
<div id="menu-header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>
<div id="menu-body">
    <p>MENU BODY</p>
</div>
```

Try something like:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-header">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-body">
        <p>MENU BODY</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That way if you want to move the menu and everything in it you can write a CSS rule like this:

```
#menu {float:left;margin:15px 0 0 25px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

just another one! ;-)

**full-working-demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/converting-tables-to-css-layers

hope this help!

Comment: ahh, that's pretty cool! I have saved it, that's pretty good!